# How to convert equation from R code into readable text?

Tags: r

I have defined multiple different functions, each containing one equation each, like so:

```
catalanFormula <- function(n){
    return( (factorial(2 * n)) / ((factorial(n + 1)) * factorial(n)) )
  }
triangularFormula <- function(n){
    return( (n * (n+1)) / 2 )
}
```

I am then plotting each function using the plot() function from base R. What I want to do is be able to include the equation in my plot as a label or text, but in a way that is easily understandable. I know I can use LaTeX to write each equation manually, but I was wondering if there is a package or method anyone knows of that can deparse a mathematical equation in R and turn it into a standard readable mathematical equation. The only math occurring is factorials, multiplication, division, exponents, addition, and subtraction.

For example, I want to convert

```
(factorial(2 * n)) / ((factorial(n + 1)) * factorial(n))
```

into something that looks like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkV1I.png)
Then, be able to use the output within the text() function of base R plotting.

Comment: You want to do this for every possible R function and mathematical symbol? I'm afraid that seems overly ambitious. There's no such base R function to do that because there's not always a direct mapping from code to latex output. The are the `?plotmath` constructs for certain latex-like formatting of R expressions, but there's no special formatting for functions like `factorial()`. You'd need to define some sort of translation yourself. If you limit the scope a small list of functions you want to translate, it may be possible.

Comment: Does it need to be in R?  A number of symbolic math engines do this, such as Mathematica, Maxima, MathCad, Sage...  As an example, I pasted your equation `( (factorial(2 * n)) / ((factorial(n + 1)) * factorial(n)) )` into [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28+%28factorial%282+*+n%29%29+%2F+%28%28factorial%28n+%2B+1%29%29+*+factorial%28n%29%29+%29) and that worked nicely.

Comment: @MrFlick I will edit my post to reflect this, but the only math in the equations are factorials and basic arithmetic, meaning exponents, addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division. I will look into writing some form of translator, thank you!

Comment: @dww Yes, it needs to be in R. I will edit my post to reflect this, but I am outputting graphs using these formulas and would like to be able to label each graph with the corresponding formula.

Comment: `simsalapar::expr2latex()` looks promising for some expressions, but unfortunately that doesn't seem to include factorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a base R function that will walk the abstract syntax tree to replace the factorial and `/` functions with the corresponding `?plotmath` markup so you can add them to R plots.

```
returnToPlotmath <- function(fun) {
  swap <- function(x) {
    if (class(x) %in% c("call","(")) {
      x <- as.list(x)
      if (as.character(x[[1]])=="/") {
        x[[1]] = quote(frac)
        x[[2]] = swap(x[[2]])
        x[[3]] = swap(x[[3]])
      } else if (as.character(x[[1]])=="factorial") {
        x[[1]] = quote(`*`)
        if (is.call(x[[2]])) {
          x[[2]] = as.call(list(quote(`(`), x[[2]]))
        } else {
          x[[2]] = swap(x[[2]])
        }
        x[[3]] = "!"
      } else if (as.character(x[[1]])=="*") {
        if(is.call(x[[2]]) | is.call(x[[3]])) {
          x[[1]] = quote(`%.%`)
          x[[2]] = swap(x[[2]])
          x[[3]] = swap(x[[3]])
        }
      } else {
        x[[2]] = swap(x[[2]])
        if (length(x)==3) x[[3]] = swap(x[[3]])
      }
      return(as.call(x))
    } else {
      return(x)
    }
  }
  body_exprs <- body(fun)[[2]]
  swap(body_exprs[[length(body_exprs)]])
}
```

This does assume that the `return` is the last statement in the function body `{}` block. You can get the expression with

```
returnToPlotmath(catalanFormula)
# frac(((2 * n) * "!"), (((n + 1) * "!") %.% (n * "!")))
returnToPlotmath(triangularFormula)
# frac((n %.% (n + 1)), 2)
```

And you can add them to plot titles and such

```
plot(main=returnToPlotmath(catalanFormula), 1, 1)
plot(main=returnToPlotmath(triangularFormula), 1, 1)
```

[image: catalanFormula]
[image: triangularFormula]

This solution is highly specific to the functions you need to transform. But it could be extended if needed.

Comment: This worked perfectly for what I needed to accomplish, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

With the **Ryacas** package you can transform a math expression to its corresponding LaTeX code. But the factorial must be given as `!`:

```
library(Ryacas)
eq <- yac_symbol("(2 * n)! / ((n + 1)! * n!)")
tex(eq)
# "\\frac{\\left( 2 n\\right) !}{\\left( n + 1\\right) ! n!}"
```

Another possibility is to call Python from R and use the **pytexit** library:

```
from pytexit import py2tex
py2tex("math.factorial(2 * n) / ((factorial(n + 1)) * factorial(n))")
# $$\frac{\operatorname{factorial}\left(2n\right)}{\operatorname{factorial}\left(n+1\right) \operatorname{factorial}\left(n\right)}$$
```

You can also take a look at [PyLaTeX](https://jeltef.github.io/PyLaTeX/current/index.html) and [lax](https://github.com/iogf/lax).

Answer (score 2):

The `expr2latex()` function from `simsalapar` parses expressions to LaTeX, and can be extended to include the factorial symbol with a minor addition to the code:

```
expr2latex2 <- function(expr) {
  L <- length(expr)
  c.BinTable <- simsalapar:::c.BinTable
  if(!L) "" else {
    Symb <- is.symbol(expr)
    F <- if(Symb) expr else expr[[1]]
    cF <- simsalapar:::mDeparse(F)
    FF <- simsalapar:::renderAtom(F, Len=L, d.a = cF)
    if(Symb && L != 1)
      stop("is.symbol(.), but length(.) = ", L, " != 1")
    else if(!Symb && typeof(expr) != "language" && L != 1)
      stop("is not language nor symbol), but length(.) = ", L, " != 1")
     switch(L,
           ## length 1:
           FF,
           
           { ## length 2: e.g.  "- 1", "+ x", "!TRUE",  "~ ff",
             #browser()
             rhs <- expr2latex2(expr[[2]])
             if       (cF == "bold") paste0("\\mathbf{", rhs, "}")
             else if(cF == "italic") paste0("\\mathit{", rhs, "}")
             else if(cF == "factorial")  paste0("(",rhs,")!")   #extra case added in for factorial
             else if(!simsalapar:::isOp(cF)) # not a binary operator ==> "function call":
               paste0(FF,"(",rhs,")") ## e.g. "O(n)"
             else if(cF == "{") paste0("{", rhs, "}")
             else if(cF == "(") paste0("(", rhs, ")")
             else paste(FF, rhs)
           },
           
           { ## length 3:
             lhs <- expr2latex2(expr[[2]])
             rhs <- expr2latex2(expr[[3]])
             if(cF == "[") ## subscript
               paste0(lhs, "_{", rhs, "}")
             else if(cF == "~") ## space
               paste(lhs, "\\", rhs)
             ## not treated, as plotmath() does neither :
             ## else if(cF == "[[")
             ##     paste0(lhs, "[[", rhs, "]]")
             else if(cF %in% c.BinTable)
               paste(lhs, simsalapar:::getTab(cF, simsalapar:::BinTable), rhs)
             else if(cF %in% c.RelTable)
               paste(lhs, simsalapar:::getTab(cF, simsalapar:::RelTable), rhs)
             else if(simsalapar:::isOp(cF)) ## e.g.   U + x
               paste(lhs, FF, rhs)
             else ## log(x, 2)
               paste0(FF, "(", lhs, ",", rhs, ")")
           },
           
           ## length >=4 : F(a, b, c, ...)
           stop("length(expr) = ",L," (>= 4);  not yet implemented") # TODO MM
    )## end{switch}
  }
}
```

original function

```
expr2latex( quote( (factorial(2 * n)) / ((factorial(n + 1)) * factorial(n)) ) )
#[1] "(factorial(2   n)) / ((factorial(n + 1))   factorial(n))"
```

revised treatment of factorials

```
expr2latex2( quote( (factorial(2 * n)) / ((factorial(n + 1)) * factorial(n)) ) )
#[1] "((2   n)!) / (((n + 1)!)   (n)!)"
```